# Error in `[.default`(xj, i) : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to write a code to get some files for me and clean them. Some files don't quite fit my cleaning function, so I designed some code to clean them up and make them a standard format.

```
if (length(paste0("Rsa1976",files_suffixes[x])>1658)){
  n=length(paste0("Rsa1976",files_suffixes[x]))-1658
  paste0("Rsa1976",files_suffixes[x])=get(paste0("Rsa1976",files_suffixes[x]))[-c(1659:n),]
}
```

I just started getting this error:

> Error in `[.default`(xj, i) :    only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

when I tried to run the program. Does anyone know what this means?

EDIT:
In this case: files_suffixes is a list containing the suffixes of several dataframes, and "Rsa1976" is the common prefix between all these dataframes. As a result, paste0("Rsa1976",files_suffixes[x]) is referring to the dataframe whose suffix is the xth term of files_suffixes. What I am trying to do is, if the matrix has more than 1658 rows, remove those rows.

Comment: Can you post fuller code for a reproducible example? What is x? and are the *Rsa1976* series: vectors, matrices, data frames?

Comment: shouldn't your condition be: `if(length(paste0("Rsa1976",files_suffixes[x]))>1658)`?

Comment: You'll get the same error with `letters[-c(-1:1)]`. Can you see why?

Comment: `length(paste0("Rsa1976",files_suffixes[x]))` and `length(files_suffixes[x])` are equivalent. Latter removed redundant `paste0`